# Determine cl(U(x,r))

Tags: real-analysis

> Determine cl(U(x,r)) where $x$ is an element in a metric space and $U(x,r):=\{y|D(x,y)<r \}$ and $D$ is a metric defined as follows $D(x,y)=0 \iff x=y$ and $D(x,y)=1 \iff x\neq y$ and the closure is defined as the intersection of all closed sets $A \supset U(x,r)$. A set $A$ is open iff we can construct an $U(x,r)$ for all $x$ such that $U(x,r) \subset A$. A set is closed if its complementary is open.

My Problem here is that the defintion of closed is very bulky because then I would have to construct all the closed supersets of $U(x,r)$. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $\text{U}(x,1)=\{y:\text{D}(x,y)<1\}=\{x\}$ for every $x$ in your space. Therefore, any arbitrary subset $S$ will be open since $$S=\bigcup_{x\in S}\{x\},$$
is the union of open sets. Similarly, any subset will be closed since its complementary is open. Therefore, your $\text{U}(x,r)$ is closed and its closure is...

Comment: I think I get it. The singelton set is closed. Thus the smallest closed set such that $\{x\} \subset A$ is the singelton set itself. We dont't need to bother with bigger sets because we're looking at the intersection and \{x\} is already the smallest possible subset. By definition of the interior we also don't need to bother with smaller sets. Thus $cl(\{x\})=\{x\}